# Best method to gift daily coins to player without risk of abuse

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

I want my game to give a certain amount of coins as gift to the player on a daily basis so he can buy whatever he likes. What's the best way to achieve this so the system will be immune to stuff like setting the time forwards and re-starting the game , etc. It would be nice to have this working without the need to access the Internet.

Comment: Please don't use unity tag for Unity3d related questions. There's a unity3d tag for that.

Comment: I don't think that your question has anything to do with Unity, libgx or any other game engine specifically, since it's a high-level question about general principles of software design in game development and can be relevant to any particular piece of technology. I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: I understand if you don't agree with my edits I mentioned in the last comment, but why did you put the unity tag back? It has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine. May be you reverted my edits by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Client is in the hands of the enemy](http://www.raphkoster.com/gaming/laws.shtml). Whatever system you design on client side to be secure, it will be broken. If you want to have control over the player's data, you have to do it on the server.